# How to cache a node_load_multiple

Tags: 7, caching

I'm loading 5 media gallery nodes into a single page via [node_load_multiple()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7).  Unfortunately the load time is very slow, several seconds.  I read up on Drupal's caching mechanism, and [Jeff Eaton's tutorial](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/beginners-guide-caching-data-drupal-7) and got the idea that I could cache each gallery node via the `#cache` array on the node's renderable array.  I think I've set everything up correctly, but I'm not seeing any increase in performance.  Any idea what I've done wrong or neglected to include?  Here's what I've done on a page.tpl.php for the page that contains the galleries:

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids = array(1653,1654,1656,1657,1658), NULL, FALSE);
$i = 0;
$cid = "gallery_cache";
foreach ($nodes as $gallery) {
  $renderable = node_view($gallery);
  $cid .= $i;
  $renderable['#cache']['cid'] = $cid;
  $renderable['#cache']['bin'] = 'cache_page';
  $renderable['#cache']['expire'] = '1392001200';
  print drupal_render($renderable);
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results from `node_load_multiple()` are already cached within a single page load - the only time they're not is if you pass the `$reset` parameter as `TRUE` (which you're explicitly not doing). Looking at the code calls to `node_view()` don't seem to be cached, but I might be wrong there.

At a guess your performance hit might be coming from those individual calls to `node_view()`, which you might be able to mitigate a bit by using `node_view_multiple()` instead.

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(1653,1654,1656,1657,1658));
$views = node_view_multiple($nodes);

foreach ($views as $view) {
  // ...
}
```

I'm pretty sure the reason your code isn't working as you expect is that the return from `node_view()` isn't a reference to anything, so the changes you're making to the array aren't actually getting saved anywhere, only to the local copy of the array.

One last piece of advice...it would be a good idea to take this code out of the template file and put it in a preprocess function at the the theme or module level. Running database queries directly in the template file isn't the best idea for a number of reasons.

Comment: Thanks @Clive. I think what I'm looking for here is persistent caching rather than caching during the page load.  Ideally the page's 5 nodes (galleries) are cached together in this page until one of the gallery nodes is updated, then the cache is rebuilt.  This is my thought process anyway.  So my strategy should be to build a preprocessor that caches the nodes on that page so that the page's content array is saved like that.  I'm still trying to get a handle on what kind of code goes where in Drupal.